# Http live streaming to iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to *play an http live stream to iphone*, it looks like i have looked every example, mistakes and everything that i could found on the internet and apple docs about http live stream, and i think i'm in a dead end now.. I'm using `MPMoviePlayer` as in most of examples. Also i have to add the i can see the stream if i open the url from vlc player.

I succeeded in playing the **apple BipBop stream** on my iPhone that is [here](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear3/prog_index.m3u8) but can't play my stream. I figured that my url shows not in the *m3u8* file so i found this terminal command, and successfully used it.

> */Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --intf=rc rtp://@239.35.86.11:10000
>   '--sout=#transcode{fps=25,vcodec=h264,venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30, keyint=30,bframes=0,ref=1,nocabac},acodec=mp3,ab=56,audio-sync,deinterlace}:standard{mux=ts,dst=-,access=file}' | mediastreamsegmenter -b http://192.168.1.16/~Jonas/streaming/ -f
>   /users/jonas/sites/streaming/ -D*

Now i have a playlist m3u8 file locally on my machine. As i understand with the command i download stream divide it into smaller ts files and generate m3u8 file that is like a reference to those ts files. So i've tried to load this, but still no luck. For some reasons i can't even open the m3u8 file in vlc or itunes, it throws me errors. So i guess it is something wrong with the playlist file?

Maybe some of you can see what am i doing wrong here or have some suggestions how to find my problem? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try the apple http stream validator. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2235/_index.html

Comment: @Till Hey i've tried that but the stream validator gives no results, or when i give it the url of my m3u8 file it loads a lot and writes that couldn't receive file or something like that, and i don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Carefully inspect your M3U8 and check if the contained URLs are actually reachable.

Comment: @Till hey thank you for helping, but i really don't know how to inspect my m3u8, but url is reachable. I can't play the m3u8 with any of my players so it's definitely something wrong with it i guess. If i give it to mediastream validator i get no results.

Comment: The M3U8 basically is a text-file, so use any editor to check it.

Comment: @Till Everything looks ok there.. I don't get it.

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:13
#EXTINF:9.96, 
http://192.168.1.0:8080/~User/Stream/fileSequence13.ts
#EXTINF:9.9602, 
http://192.168.1.0:8080/~User/Stream/fileSequence14.ts
#EXTINF:9.9999, 
http://192.168.1.0:8080/~User/Stream/fileSequence15.ts
#EXTINF:9.9606, 
http://192.168.1.0:8080/~User/Stream/fileSequence16.ts
#EXTINF:7.9995, 
http://192.168.1.0:8080/~User/Stream/fileSequence17.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
 
something wrong maybe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5957/discussion-between-till-and-lukas)

Comment: After answering the question I realized this is very old; but for posterity -- looking at Lukas' m3u8 and comparing to my m3u8 generator code, it seems he is missing some newlines in the first few #DIRECTIVES that probably caused the issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your iOS code is just fine and that it is your server-side code that is causing issues, primarily with regards to generating the m3u8 playlist and possibly with how you're hosting the ts files that it references.

Unfortunately my example code is a bit noisy as I wrote it a year ago (it is in python) and it does a bit more than you're asking for (it live-transcodes a video into the correct m3u8/ts stuff) but it is tested and functional.

You can take a look at the code here: https://github.com/DFTi/ScribbeoServer/blob/python/transcode.py

I will paste some of the relevant methods here for your convenience; I hope it helps you:

```
  def start_transcoding(self, videoPath):
    if DISABLE_LIVE_TRANSCODE:
      print "Live transcoding is currently disabled! There is a problem with your configuration."
      return
    print "Initiating transcode for asset at path: "+videoPath
    videoPath = unquote(videoPath)
    video_md5 = md5.new(videoPath).hexdigest()
    if self.sessions.has_key(video_md5): # Session already exists?
      return self.m3u8_bitrates_for(video_md5)
    transcodingSession = TranscodeSession(self, videoPath)
    if transcodingSession.can_be_decoded():  
      self.sessions[transcodingSession.md5] = transcodingSession
      return self.m3u8_bitrates_for(transcodingSession.md5)
    else:
      return "Cannot decode this file."

  def m3u8_segments_for(self, md5_hash, video_bitrate):
    segment = string.Template("#EXTINF:$length,\n$md5hash-$bitrate-$segment.ts\n")
    partCount = math.floor(self.sessions[md5_hash].duration / 10)
    m3u8_segment_file = "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10\n"
    for i in range(0, int(partCount)):
      m3u8_segment_file += segment.substitute(length=10, md5hash=md5_hash, bitrate=video_bitrate, segment=i)
    last_segment_length = math.ceil((self.sessions[md5_hash].duration - (partCount * 10)))
    m3u8_segment_file += segment.substitute(length=last_segment_length, md5hash=md5_hash, bitrate=video_bitrate, segment=i)
    m3u8_segment_file += "#EXT-X-ENDLIST"
    return m3u8_segment_file

  def m3u8_bitrates_for(self, md5_hash):
    m3u8_fudge = string.Template(
      "#EXTM3U\n"
     # "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=384000\n"
     # "$hash-384-segments.m3u8\n"
     # "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=512000\n"
     # "$hash-512-segments.m3u8\n"
      "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=768000\n"
      "$hash-768-segments.m3u8\n"
     # "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1024000\n"
     # "$hash-1024-segments.m3u8\n"
    )
    return m3u8_fudge.substitute(hash=md5_hash)

  def segment_path(self, md5_hash, the_bitrate, segment_number):
    # A segment was requested.
    path = self.sessions[md5_hash].transcode(segment_number, the_bitrate)
    if path:
      return path
    else:
      raise "Segment path not found"
```

That project is all open source now and can be found here: https://github.com/DFTi/ScribbeoServer/tree/python

Binaries can be found here: http://scribbeo.com/server

Good luck!